# PYTHON 3.8 date range

Tags: python, loops, date, time

i trying to find all dates bettween two dates for example:
I have two dates 2019-09-21 and 2019-10-09, how can i get all dates between those  like that:

```
2019-09-21
2019-09-22
2019-09-23
2019-09-24
....
....
2019-10-08
2019-10-09
```

Comment: @FlorianBernard, this question has little to do with finding the difference between two dates, it's more about producing all dates within a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Pythonic way to do this is to create an iterator, something like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class dater(object):
    def __init__(self, first, lastPlusOne, inclusiveEnd = False):
        # Store important stuff, adjusting end if you want it inclusive.

        self.__oneDay = timedelta(days = 1)
        self.__curr = datetime.strptime(first, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        self.__term = datetime.strptime(lastPlusOne, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        if inclusiveEnd:
            self.__term += self.__oneDay

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self.next()

    def next(self):
        # This is the meat. It checks to see if the generator is
        # exhausted and raises the correct exception if so. If not,
        # it saves the current, calculates the next, stores that
        # for the next time, then returns the saved current.

        if self.__curr >= self.__term:
            raise StopIteration()

        (cur, self.__curr) = (self.__curr, self.__curr + self.__oneDay)
        return cur
```

You can call it with something like (from your example):

```
for date in dater("2019-09-21", "2019-10-09", inclusiveEnd=True):
    print(date)
```

to get:

```
2019-09-21
2019-09-22
2019-09-23
2019-09-24
2019-09-25
: no need to show it all, trust me :-)
2019-10-08
2019-10-09
```

The advantage of using an iterator is that:

- the code to use it becomes a very simple `for` loop, similar to Python's many other methods; and
- you can make the `__init__` constructor arbitrarily complex (for example, accepting `datetime` or `date` variables as well as the current strings).

That last point bears some extra explanation. In the code that sets up the `self.__curr` (for example), you can use something like this:

```
if type(first) == type(date(2000, 1, 1)):        # copy a date.
    self.__curr = first
elif type(first) == type(datetime(2000, 1, 1)):  # extract date from datetime.
    self.__curr = first.date()
else:                                            # convert string.
    self.__curr = datetime.strptime(first, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

This will detect the source type and adjust behaviour so that you get a `date` regardless. If you do the same thing for the final date, you'll get a truly adaptable iterator that can even start and end with *different* representations:

```
for mydate in dater("2000-01-01", datetime.now()):
    process_every_date_from_start_of_2000_to_yesterday(mydate)
```

Answer (score 3):

The below code can help you.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start_date = datetime.strptime('2019-09-21', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
end_date = datetime.strptime('2019-10-09', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
while start_date <= end_date:
    print(start_date)
    start_date = start_date+timedelta(days=1)
```

Output

```
2019-09-21
2019-09-22
2019-09-23
2019-09-24
2019-09-25
2019-09-26
2019-09-27
2019-09-28
2019-09-29
2019-09-30
2019-10-01
2019-10-02
2019-10-03
2019-10-04
2019-10-05
2019-10-06
2019-10-07
2019-10-08
2019-10-09
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using the built-in function `range` to create ranges, but alas, it doesn't work with dates.  Fortunately, Python dates can be converted to/from integers, which `range` CAN use:

```
from datetime import date

start_date = date(2019, 9, 21)
end_date = date(2019, 10, 9)

for ordinal in range(start_date.toordinal(), end_date.toordinal() + 1):  # Don't forget the + 1 (like I usually do)!
    print(date.fromordinal(ordinal))
```

This gives you:

```
2019-09-21
2019-09-22
2019-09-23
2019-09-24
2019-09-25
2019-09-26
2019-09-27
2019-09-28
2019-09-29
2019-09-30
2019-10-01
2019-10-02
2019-10-03
2019-10-04
2019-10-05
2019-10-06
2019-10-07
2019-10-08
2019-10-09
```

Happy dating!